# Axios/vue pass headers to allow cross origin for certain domain

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am using vue and axios and I am trying to make a global form request. Here's the problem so far everything is good however I do not know exactly where to setup cross-origin in that code. My back end has it definetely enabled and I just need to set it axios now.

Here's form:

```
  data() {
    return {
      form: new Form({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        password_confirm: ''
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.form.post('http://webuilder.app/auth/register')
        .then(response => alert('Wahoo!'));
    }
  }

form class:

import Errors from './error.js';

class Form {
  /**
   * Create a new Form instance.
   *
   * @param {object} data
   */
  constructor(data) {
    this.originalData = data;
    console.log(data);
    for (let field in data) {
      this[field] = data[field];
    }

    this.errors = new Errors();
  }


  /**
   * Fetch all relevant data for the form.
   */
  data() {
    let data = {};

    for (let property in this.originalData) {
      data[property] = this[property];
    }
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }


  /**
   * Reset the form fields.
   */
  reset() {
    for (let field in this.originalData) {
      this[field] = '';
    }

    this.errors.clear();
  }


  /**
   * Send a POST request to the given URL.
   * .
   * @param {string} url
   */
  post(url) {
    console.log(url);
    return this.submit('post', url);
  }


  /**
   * Send a PUT request to the given URL.
   * .
   * @param {string} url
   */
  put(url) {
    return this.submit('put', url);
  }


  /**
   * Send a PATCH request to the given URL.
   * .
   * @param {string} url
   */
  patch(url) {
    return this.submit('patch', url);
  }


  /**
   * Send a DELETE request to the given URL.
   * .
   * @param {string} url
   */
  delete(url) {
    return this.submit('delete', url);
  }


  /**
   * Submit the form.
   *
   * @param {string} requestType
   * @param {string} url
   */
  submit(requestType, url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(this.data());
      console.log(url);
      console.log(requestType);
      axios.post(url, this.data())
        .then(response => {
          this.onSuccess(response.data);
          console.log(response);
          resolve(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.onFail(error);
          console.log(error);
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }


  /**
   * Handle a successful form submission.
   *
   * @param {object} data
   */
  onSuccess(data) {
    alert(data.message); // temporary

    this.reset();
  }


  /**
   * Handle a failed form submission.
   *
   * @param {object} errors
   */
  onFail(errors) {
    this.errors.record(errors);
  }
}

export default Form;
```

global axios settings:

window.axios = Axios;

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://webuilder.app'
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
```

Any ideas why it is still being rejected and how to fix this issue?

Comment: what errors do you get? usually, only the backend needs to enable cors

Comment: it sends OPTIONS request upon submit which is a 200 but then nothing else. I get a warning in dev tools saying The "policy on the same origin" has not disappeared at the place where it is located, "http://webuilder.app/auth/register". (CORS "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header does not match "(null)")

Comment: so it's sending OPTIONS but not the POST request

Comment: I don't understand why you are telling axios about cors. It is the backend service ex: express.js that needs to send the headers. setting it in front-end from axios does nothing

Comment: Yeah I reliased I don't have to, but why is it sending OPTiONS request and not the post?

Comment: the post is preceded by options in most cases. I have the same process in my  code

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/475

Comment: how does that link solve a solution? not entirely sure. I allow all cross site origins on my backend

Comment: I just tried doing post throught insomnia and it works fine